# How to get an output from microstack GPS with an C# application?

Tags: windows, spi, windows-iot, gps

we're currently working with my friend on a functional GPS module whcih will get your location etc. But we're stuck on this thing, we know that our device communicates and this is the ouput we got

```
"System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{DCDE6AF9-6610-4285-828F-CAAF78C424CC}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.Spb.ControllerFriendlyName:=\"SPI0\"" string
```

We're working with Windows 10 IoT and we don't know what to do next, or maybe the answer is right in front of us but we can't see it.

Comment: It would help if you showed your used classes and code

Comment: We've found a way how to solve it 8)

Comment: You should answer your own question for the sake of others who may also have the same problem.